# Enviar dados do template para o banco de dados

Tags: python, django

Estou enfrentando um problema que em django, em que o meu formulário não consegue ser validado, portanto, não insere os dados no banco. Eu quero que o usuário tenha a opção de adicionar um professor. A estrutura do formulário está ok, mas é como se a requisição não chegasse nem a ser feita. Já tentei de diversas formas e nenhuma delas serviu. Segue o código abaixo.

Arquivo views.py:

```
def adiciona_professor(request):
    form = AdicionaProfessor()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AdicionaProfessor(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            nome = form.cleaned_data['nomecompleto_professor']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email_professor']
            cpf = form.cleaned_data['cpf']
            salvando = Professor(nomecompleto_professor=nome, email_professor=email, cpf=cpf)
            salvando.save()

    return render(request, 'evento_detalhe.html', locals())
```

Arquivo forms.py:

```
class AdicionaProfessor(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
       model = Professor
       fields = ('nomecompleto_professor', 'email_professor', 'cpf', )
```

`template`:

```
<div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" style="background: linear-gradient(90deg,#9cd116, #0AF6AE); font-weight: 100;">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-target="#collapse" data-toggle="collapse" style="color: #0b2e13; font-size: 1.2rem">
                       Adicionar professor
                    </button>
                </div>


                <!--
                  * No bloco abaixo, constam as informações dos cards
                -->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapse">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form.as_p }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputName1">Nome Completo</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1">{{formulario}}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Endereço de email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Seu email" {{email}}
                            </div>

                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputCPF">CPF</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputCPF" aria-describedby="emailHelp"{{cpf}}>
                            </div>

                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Cadastrar">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Eu deixei um `print('Chegou')` para ver se o formulários sequer chegava no trecho `form.is_valid()`, mas não chegou.

Já agradeço pela atenção!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria a view um pouco diferente. Acredito que o problema está ali.

```
def adiciona_professor(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AdicionaProfessor(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            professor = form.save(commit=False)
            professor.nomecompleto_professor = form.cleaned_data['nomecompleto_professor']
            professor.email_professor = form.cleaned_data['email_professor']
            professor.cpf = form.cleaned_data['cpf']
            professor.save()
    else:
        form = AdicionaProfessor()

    return render(request, 'evento_detalhe.html', locals())
```

Comment: eu fiquei pensando nisso... será q chamar duas vezes o form pode causar conflito? tirar da primeira linha parece um caminho adequado

Comment: Eu fiz a tentativa do seu código, exatamente como está aí. Nada aconteceu

Comment: Paulo, de fato, o problema estava na view. O colega Carlos, abaixo, fez uma pergunta sobre a situação da urls.py e do admin.py. Eu não os modifiquei, porém adicionei uma nova view. Acontece que o formulário já era dentro de uma view previamente feita, portanto, o "adiciona_professor" não deveria existir. O código foi colocado na view correta e, enfim, funcionou! Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AdicionaProfessor(request.POST)
```

vc diz que seu método aparentemente sequer passa pelo  `form.is_valid()` muito provavelmente porque o método que a **view** recebe não é uma string `POST` e como não há um else, nada é feito.

a princípio, pra vc entender o que acontece coloque algo assim:

```
print(request.method)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AdicionaProfessor(request.POST)
    ...
else
    print(f'o trecho {request.method} está sendo executado no else'}
```

se você conseguir ver no console os prints significa que realmente não está passando pela primeira condicional, então uma solução é:

```
print(request.method)
if str(request.method) == 'POST':
    form = AdicionaProfessor(request.POST)
    ... # todo o resto do código aqui
else
    print(f'o {request.method} está sendo executado no else'}
```

transforma a request numa string que provavelmente o código vai passar no trecho

Comment: Então, Carlos, ele não executou nada. :/

Comment: eita... como está o urls.py e admin.py?

Comment: Eu não fiz nenhuma modificação neles. O usuário adiciona um professor por um card do bootstrap. Não é aberto nenhuma tela para o formulário.

Comment: Consegui. A tua pergunta de como estava o urls.py e o admin.py foram o Eureka! para a resposta hahaha. Muito obrigada!

Comment: hahahahahahahahahaha... beodeos hahaha ok... se tá funcionando, tá bom

Answer (score 0):

**function based views**

```
  def adiciona_professor(request):
        form = AdicionaProfessor(request.POST or None) #post ou None
        if str(request.method) == 'POST': # comparando com uma string
            if form.is_valid():   # verifica se esta okay
                nome = form.cleaned_data['nomecompleto_professor']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email_professor']
                cpf = form.cleaned_data['cpf']
               #salvar
                messages.success(request,"tarefa concluida!")
                form = ContatoForms()
            else:
                messages.error(request,"Erro!")
    
        context ={"form":form}
        return render(request, "evento_detalhe.html", context)
```

class Based views, simplifica bem mais que função